# Lebesgue integral preserves the inequality

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions such that $f\le g$ and the Lebesgue integral $\int g$ is finite. By finite I mean that $\int g$ is a real number. I want to show that $\int f$ is also finite. This result is intuitive but I don't know how to prove it formally. The only way that comes to my mind is restoring to the definition of Lebesgue integral but it seems that it's unnecessary lengthy proof. Is there any shorter proof for this result?

Comment: Do you mean that $\int g$ is defined and less than $+\infty$ but may be $-\infty$? In that case $f^{+} \leq g^{+}$ proves the result.

Comment: @geetha290krm I mean that $\int g$ is a real number.

Comment: In Measure Theory $\int g$ being a real number is same as saying that $\int |g| <\infty$ which is usually expressed by saying that $g$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g=0$ and $f(x) =-1$. Then $g$ is integrable and $f \leq g$ but $f$ is not integrable. ($\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx=-\infty$)

If $0 \leq f \leq g$ then $0 \leq \int fd\mu \leq gd\mu<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. So, under what conditions we have $\int f \lt \infty$? I think $0\le f\le g$ is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, $0 \leq f \leq g$ (or $|f| \leq |g|$) would suffice.  @S.H.W

Comment: In the case $0\le f\le g$, how it can be proved that $\int f \lt \infty$? I think it would be nice if you add the proof to the answer, if you like.

Comment: @S.H.W I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand why the implication $0 \leq f \leq g \implies 0 \leq \int fd\mu \leq gd\mu<\infty$ is true. Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: $\int f$ is defined as  the supremum of $\int s$ over all non-negative simple functions $s \leq f$. Since $s\leq f$ implies $s \leq g$ we get $\int f \leq \int g$. @S.H.W